# How can I handle firebase library exceptions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, nest-api

My Nodejs Server is crashing due to the exception in firebase-node.js library!

```
var thermostateTree = nestAccounts[self.mac].firebaseClient.child('devices').child('thermostats').child(self.id);  

var callback = function(err){
if (err)
  logger.info('[%s] [Nest] [setTargetTemperature] failed to set target temperature. ', self.mac);
else
  logger.info('[%s] [Nest] [setTargetTemperature] target temperature changed', self.mac);
};

thermostateTree.update({
 'target_temperature_high_f' : max_temperature,
 'target_temperature_low_f' : min_temperature
}, callback);
```

How can I handle following exception?

> uncaughtException: BLOCKED: {"error":"blocked","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#blocked","message":"blocked","instance":"d7d74b5c-325b-4360-bf77-7c7f9e385caf"} date=Wed Jun 29 2016 02:49:34 GMT-0400 (EDT), pid=9737, uid=1000, gid=1000, cwd=/home/centos/NodeJSCID, execPath=/usr/bin/node, version=v0.10.40, argv=[/usr/bin/node, /home/centos/NodeJSCID/server-xmpp.js, slave, nest], rss=189448192, heapTotal=137562624, heapUsed=87270704, loadavg=[0.0029296875, 0.0341796875, 0.04541015625], uptime=5355060.0423008, trace=[column=null, file=null, function=Error, line=null, method=null, native=false, column=115, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=null, line=226, method=null, native=false, column=165, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=ec, line=52, method=null, native=false, column=23, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=Pi, line=226, method=null, native=false, column=435, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=null, line=222, method=null, native=false, column=355, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=null, line=184, method=null, native=false, column=104, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=Rh.h.Jd, line=186, method=h.Jd, native=false, column=364, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=Fh.Jd, line=176, method=Jd, native=false, column=280, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=wh.Jg, line=174, method=Jg, native=false, column=464, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=zh, line=168, method=null, native=false, column=321, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js, function=Ka.onmessage, line=167, method=onmessage, native=false, column=30, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api/event_target.js, function=EventTarget.dispatchEvent, line=22, method=dispatchEvent, native=false, column=10, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js, function=instance._receiveMessage, line=134, method=_receiveMessage, native=false, column=49, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js, function=, line=34, method=null, native=false, column=20, file=events.js, function=emit, line=117, method=null, native=false, column=14, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js, function=, line=451, method=null, native=false, column=40, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js, function=pipe, line=37, method=null, native=false, column=3, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js, function=Pipeline._loop, line=44, method=_loop, native=false, column=8, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js, function=Pipeline.processIncomingMessage, line=13, method=processIncomingMessage, native=false, column=20, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/websocket_extensions.js, function=instance.processIncomingMessage, line=133, method=processIncomingMessage, native=false, column=22, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js, function=instance._emitMessage, line=442, method=_emitMessage, native=false, column=19, file=/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js, function=instance._emitFrame, line=405, method=_emitFrame, native=false], stack=[Error: BLOCKED: {"error":"blocked","type":"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#blocked","message":"blocked","instance":"d7d74b5c-325b-4360-bf77-7c7f9e385caf"},     at Error (),     at /home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:226:115,     at ec (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:52:165),     at Pi (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:226:23),     at /home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:222:435,     at /home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:184:355,     at Rh.h.Jd (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:186:104),     at Fh.Jd (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:176:364),     at wh.Jg (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:174:280),     at zh (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:168:464),     at Ka.onmessage (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:167:321),     at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api/event_target.js:22:30),     at instance._receiveMessage (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js:134:10),     at null. (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js:34:49),     at emit (events.js:117:20),     at null. (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:451:14),     at pipe (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js:37:40),     at Pipeline._loop (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js:44:3),     at Pipeline.processIncomingMessage (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js:13:8),     at instance.processIncomingMessage (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/websocket_extensions.js:133:20),     at instance._emitMessage (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:442:22),     at instance._emitFrame (/home/centos/NodeJSCID/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:405:19)]

Comment: May be you can share some code?

Comment: What version of the Firebase node SDK are you using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using version 2.4.2

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I have added the code as well!

Comment: I don't know the exact case in which this exception occurs! Sometimes this exception occurs, while sometimes everything work fine!

Comment: The NEST API requires the use of Firebase SDK versions 1.x. See https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/firebase-client-libraries#web-client-library